# Get Query is not working when using HQL in Hibernate Spatial

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, hibernate-spatial

I am using Spring boot along with Hibernate for a Spatial query.
Libraries used:
1. Spring boot - 2.1.3.RELEASE
2. Hibernate Spatial - 5.3.7.Final
3. MariaDB - mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.36-MariaDB

Whenever I use HQL as depicted below in Query, I am getting the following error during application startup however when I try using native query it works.

I have tried with different dialects. Also, tried using columnDefinition with value as geometry, geolatte-geometry.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        physical_naming_strategy: com.orange.alc.polygon.dao.config.DefaultNamingStrategy 
        format_sql: false
        dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect 

@Entity
public class PolygonMasterEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  // Here we have used Geolatte library
  private Polygon geometry;

  @Column(name = "is_active")
  private Boolean active;

  @Column(name = "is_deleted")
  private Boolean deleted;
}

@Repository
public interface PolygonMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<PolygonMasterEntity, Long>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<PolygonMasterEntity> {

  @Query("select master from #{#entityName} master WHERE" 
      + " and within(master.geometry, :point)")
  List<PolygonMasterEntity> findCostUsingPointForLLME(
      @Param("point") Point point);

}
```

Currently, I am getting the following error during startup:

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: ( near line 1, column 164 [select master from com.orange.alc.polygon.dao.entity.PolygonMasterEntity master WHERE within(master.geometry, :point)]

```
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:277)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:191)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:143)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:119)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:595)
~~~~~~~~~   at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:704)
~~~~~~~~~   ... 100 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You cannot use `: ` to delimit properties for `spring.jpa.properties` they have to use `.`. The properties are used as is and thus don't support the `:`. So use `hibernate.dialect` instead etc. This applies to all the properties under the `spring.jpa.properties` namespace. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17975

Comment: Also, I have debugged it further and the exception is happening form HqlSqlBaseWalker class under package org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr. It does not have any token for spatial methods. at  line org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2146)

Comment: Because the wrong dialect is mapped, which is due to use of wrong properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have `and` right behind `WHERE` in your query. 
I don't think that is legit HQL and you should drop the `and`.

Comment: Tried just now. Even after that, it is not working code corrected

Answer (score 0):

The properties under `spring.jpa.properties` are used as is and directly passed to JPA as a `Map`. As Spring (Boot) doesn't parse these you cannot use the normal YAML syntax but have to include the property names as is with a `.`. This is also explained [in this Github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17975) and the [Spring Boot Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-jpa-properties).

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    properties:
      hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
      hibernate.physical_naming_strategy: com.orange.alc.polygon.dao.config.DefaultNamingStrategy 
      hibernate.format_sql: false
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQLSpatialDialect
```

Should work and set the proper dialect.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. I have made the changes as suggested. Still no luck. The same error persist.

Comment: Also, I would like to add those properties with ":" are also working. I can see it in logs. Perhaps, some update fixed that issue.

Comment: No it hasn't. You can see the properties, they simply won't get mapped to the proper place. This is also what is documented.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is not working even after the changes.